# Strange LANG locale in sabayon

Tags: linux, locale, gentoo

I use Sabayon 14.01 Xfce now, and I find a strange problem with the locale.

When open a new xfce-terminal, `echo $LANG` will output `zh_CN.utf8`, and command `locale` will output similar content.

`zh_CN.utf8` is a strange locale variable, this leads gVim's menu content empty(in Chinese).
The normal LANG variable should be `zh_CN.UTF-8`, and gVim work fine with it.

When execute command `source /etc/profile`, the strange LANG variable return to normal(`zh_CN.utf8` -> `zh_CN.UTF-8`).

But strange LANG variable still survives when login or in a new xfce-terminal.

So, how to set default LANG variable to be the normal one?

-- UPDATE @ 2014-01-18 ---

I re-installed Sabayon xfce and found that the UPDATE lead to this problem.
After re-installed, the locale was the right one, `zh_CN.utf-8`.
After UPDATE, the locale changed to `zh_CN.utf8`, in Xfce GUI login.
In tty (alt+ctrl + f1), login and `locale` , the result is the right one.

---

-- REPLY TO ZermeX --

I have checked that `/etc.locale.gen` , `/etc/env.d/02locale` , `/etc/profile`, `~/.bashrc`, `~/.xprofile` and so on for times. These are quite fine.

I am certain of this problem caused by the update. `lightdm` MAYBE the suspect.

verion update of lightdm:

- lightdm gtk greeter:  1.3.1-r1 => 1.6.1~0
- lightdm base: 1.4.0 => 1.8.5-r1~0

I also found a quite similar bug been reported to debian: [Debian Bug report logs - #735251 lightdm: user locale tweaks are clobbered by non-default locale](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=735251) .But the version of `lightdm` is higher.

Answer (score 1):

Please run `eselect locale list` and verify that the correct locale is set.

Also check your ~/.bashrc (or whatever shell you use) if you accidentally overwrite the LANG from /etc/profile in your settings.

-- Reply to UPDATE @ 2014-01-18 --

For further help i would like to see the output of the following commands

```
eselect locale list
cat /etc/locale.gen
cat /etc/env.d/02locale
cat /etc/profile
cat ~/.bashrc
```

Also it would be helpful to know how you start X. Do you use a graphical display manager or do you run the startx command? Depending on what you use it would also be helpful to see the output of `cat ~/.xinitrc` or `cat ~/.xsession` and the display managers configuration files.